# Converting Mutable to Immutable with Hibernate

Tags: hibernate, grails, groovy, immutability

I'm using Grails and I have the following domain class:

```
class Pack {
  String code

  Date publishedDate
  //several other properties (including collections hasMany)....

  def isPublished() {
    return publishedDate != null
  }

  def publish() {
    publishedDate = new Date()    
  }

  def canEdit() {
    return !isPublished()
  }
}
```

To sell a Pack I first need publish it and I use the publish method to publicate a Pack.

After published, a Pack cannot be changed (i.e. after published, a Pack need to be a immutable instance).

My question is:

- How to transform a Mutable object in Immutable using Groovy?

or

- Is there a way to retrieve a Immutable instance from Hibernate?

Another option is to use the canEdit() method combined with the Hibernate events (beforeUpdate and beforeDelete). If canEdit() == false then I can throw a RuntimeException inside the beforeDelete or beforeUpdate. Is a good solution?

Obs.: I think that the freeze method in Ruby does exactly what I need. (http://rubylearning.com/satishtalim/mutable_and_immutable_objects.html)

Answer (score 1):

you can use `Pack.read( id )` to get

> an instance of the domain class for the specified id in a read-only state. null is returned if the row with the specified id doesn't exist.

see http://grails.org/doc/latest/ref/Domain%20Classes/read.html

Comment: Thanks for the answer @injecteer, but the method read isn't what I expect. Although the automatic flush is disabled, the object itself is not truely a read-only object. From the Grails help: "The instance isn't truly read-only - you can modify it - but if it isn't explicitly saved but has been modified, it won't be updated in the database during a flush". Moreover, the solution doesn't apply to the collections (as you can see in the help)...

Comment: ...I need a more robust solution. Because of that I'm searching a Hibernate solution that grants me that the whole object, properties and collections, are truely read-only. I don't think that this solution exists, though.