# Making an attribute immutable in GORM

Tags: grails, grails-orm

I want to make an attribute immutable in the GORM. So that once it is set, it can't be changed.  For example, a Product sku or a person's social security number.   What is the recommended way to do this?

Comment: I asked it some time ago and didin't receive an answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17582593/converting-mutable-to-immutable-with-hibernate

Answer (score 5):

It depends on what level of immutable you want. If you simply don't want changes persisted to the database then using the `updateable: false` mapping would work. The [documentation](http://grails.github.io/grails-doc/latest/ref/Database%20Mapping/updateable.html) explains this further.

For example:

```
class Product {
  String sku
  ...
  static mapping = {
    sku updateable: false
  }
  ...
}
```

Comment: Thanks that's great will do that.  What about at code level?  If I make the attribute final, can the GORM fall over?

Comment: If you set the property to `final` then you won't be able to assign a value to it when you create an instance. `final` is meant to be used with a value that is defined with the data type, for example: `final String name = 'bob'` and not assigned through a setter. If you want to make the property only assignable ONCE you can implement a custom setter. Something like this: `setName(String s) { if (name) return; name = s; }` which will ignore setting it once name has an initial value.

Comment: A property can also be final though if you just are using the constructor. The problem then is that a version of the GORM may say, I am not using the constructor I am only using the setter